# I need to create a model like a sql table on alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts, alfresco-maven

I need to create a model for cities that contains only the fields id, city name, like a sql table but without creating a file that is not inheriting any Alfresco model (content, folder, etc). I can do that? or it is obligatory to inherit from the Alfresco models

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By seeing the definition of **sys:base** (root object) :

```
<type name="sys:base">
  <title>Base</title>
  <mandatory-aspects>
    <aspect>sys:referenceable</aspect>
    <aspect>sys:localized</aspect>
  </mandatory-aspects>
</type>
```

I would say that it should be possible to create a type without inheriting from something.

But the best shot would be to do the try.

You can inherit from **sys:base** anyway.

Comment: I think that using sys:base is a good idea. The aspect sys:referenceable that will be added automatically is useful. The other aspect added automatically, sys:localized, is not really useful, but it won't create problems.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a datalist like this to achieve that.

```
<description>Cities Data List Content model</description>
<version>1.0</version>

<imports>
    <!-- Import Alfresco Dictionary Definitions -->
    <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/dictionary/1.0" prefix="d"/>
    <!-- Import Alfresco Content Domain Model Definitions -->
    <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0" prefix="cm"/>
    <!-- Import Alfresco Data List Model Definitions -->
    <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/datalist/1.0"   prefix="dl" />
</imports>


<namespaces>
    <namespace uri="<<Your uri>>" prefix="cities"/>
</namespaces>

<types>
    <!--
        Data List Item Type for the custom cities list
        -->
    <type name="cities:cityListItem">
        <title>Cities List Item</title>
        <parent>dl:dataListItem</parent>
        <properties>
            <property name="cities:cityName">
                <type>d:text</type>
                <mandatory>true</mandatory>
            </property>
            <property name="cities:cityID">
                <type>d:int</type>
                <mandatory>true</mandatory>
            </property>
            <property name="cities:cityDescription">
                <type>d:text</type>
            </property>

        </properties>

    </type>
</types>
```

You can later  add more customization related  to this datalist as you can see in here:
https://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/references/dev-extension-points-data-lists.html

Comment: DataList is a good idea but is going to disapear : https://ecmarchitect.com/archives/2017/12/02/4305

Comment: It is ok  in alfresco 4 and 5.When alfresco 6 comes out it might not be correct but i think it will still work

Comment: I do not think that it is a good idea to use data-lists. They are deprecated and they had never been supported very well.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using AttributeService.

http://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/references/dev-services-attribute.html